# Update all documents in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have made a change in my documents, one string field now is an array and the name also changed.
So it went from:

```
phoneNumber: "+34616161616"
```

to:

```
phone: {
    phoneNumber: "616161616",
    phoneCode: "+34",
    isoCode: "ES"
}
```

After doing the refactor in my app I was supporting also the old version but I realised that I'd need to do many changes.

Can I updated instead all documents in Firestore? Is there any way inside Firebase to update this at once?

The structure is:

> 1- Users (collection) --> userId --> portfolios (collection) -->
> portfolioId --> rents (collection) --> collectionId --> phone
>
> 2- Users (collection) --> userId --> contacts (collection) -->
> contactId --> phone

Comment: Yes, you can certainly write code to update many documents.  You will have to query for and update each document individually.

Comment: But I'm not talking to do this individually from my app. There is way to do this in one single function/option from Firebase directly?

Comment: Also what about if I have a free account and hundreds of records?

Comment: No, there is no bulk update operation like a SQL "update where" clause.  You have to call out each document individually.

Comment: that's insane srl. Google team cannot expect from us to do so. Again, what happens if I'm a free user? I'm going to exceed my quota. ATM I don't have a big database but when I will, I'm not sure how is going to be the support if we are already having simple problems like this

Comment: If Firestore doesn't meet your specific needs, then there are other options for building your app.  Every database comes with strengths and limitations that need to be managed.

Comment: of course there are options, but that's not the solution for a problem

Comment: The solution is exactly as I stated - query, iterate, and update individually. You really don't have any other options with Firestore.

Comment: that's a shame TBH

Comment: Can you propose it as an answer? The other one is about to update some values, but not the param name

Answer (score 1):

```
functions.firestore.document('/accounts/{accountId}/resources/{resourceId}')
```

.onUpdate((change, context) => {
const resource = context.params.resourceId;

```
return admin.firestore().collection('/accounts/'+account+'/tasks')
  .where('resourceId', '=', resource).get().then(snapshot => {
    const promises = [];
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      promises.push(doc.ref.update({
        fieldA: 'valueA',
        fieldB: 'valueB'
      }));
    });
    return Promise.all(promises)
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
  return null;
});
```

});
this should work to update your documents

Comment: cannot do this from Firebase directly? Do I need to perform this from my app? Also why should I pass a resourceId when I want to update all of them?

Comment: also that update will update the value of that document, but not the params name